# MonoGame Key Pressed String

Tags: c#, keyboard, monogame, getstring, getstate

In MonoGame, how can I read which keyboard key is pressed in the form of a String?

I have tried `String pressedKey = Keyboard.GetState().ToString();`, but it gives me "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.KeyboardState".

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Get the player to type thier name perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In games, you typically think of keys as buttons that have state rather than strings because you are usually checking if a button is up or down to move a character around, shoot, jump, etc.

As others have said, you said you should use IsKeyDown and IsKeyUp if you already know what keys you want to test. However, sometimes you just want to know what keys are being pressed. For that, you can use the GetPressedKeys method which will give you an array of keys currently pressed on the keyboard.

If you wanted to turn those keys into a string, you could probably do something like this in your update method.

```
    private string _stringValue = string.Empty;

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        var keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        var keys = keyboardState.GetPressedKeys();

        if(keys.Length > 0)
        {
            var keyValue = keys[0].ToString();
            _stringValue += keyValue;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

However, keep in mind that this won't be perfect. You'd have to add extra code to handle the SHIFT key for upper and lowercase letters and you would want to filter out other keys like Ctrl and Alt. Perhaps restrict the input to only alphanumeric values and so on..

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Too little rep to comment but if you only want to allow A-Z as input and you're using Monogame (and XNA maybe) you can look at the Keys enum and see if the key value you're testing for is within that range.

Something along the lines of

```
if((int)key > 64 && (int)key <  91)
   {
      keyValue = key.ToString();
      this.EnteredString += keyValue;
   }
```

Where 64 is the key below A in the enum and 91 is the key above z in the enum :)

You can allow numbers with the same idea :

```
else if ((int)key > 47 && (int)key < 58)
     {
     keyValue = key.ToString();
     keyValue = keyValue.TrimStart('D');

     this.EnteredString += keyValue;
     }
```

and will trim the unwanted "D" character which shows up

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `.ToString()` function to find out what key(s) are pressed.

You need to track the `KeyboardState` in order to find out which key(s) are/were pressed. e.g.

```
KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState()
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) {
   // Move forward
}
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) {
   // Move backward
}
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) {
   // Move left
}
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) {
   // Move right
}
```

Comment: The OP might want the string value of the key pressed for input box type entries - e.g. New high score, enter your initals, or Character Name: etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered already, but I found this [topic](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/457783-xna-getting-text-from-keyboard/) here, and did a little refactoring in some code there:

```
public class KeyboardStringReader
    {
        private KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
        private KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;

        public string TextString { get; set; }
        public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
        public KeyboardStringReader()
        {
            TextString = string.Empty;
            IsFinished = false;
        }

        public void UpdateInput()
        {
            if (!this.IsFinished)
            {
                oldKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;
                currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

                Keys[] pressedKeys;
                pressedKeys = currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys();

                foreach (Keys key in pressedKeys)
                {
                    if (oldKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(key))
                    {
                        if (key == Keys.Back && TextString.Length > 0)
                        {
                            TextString = TextString.Remove(TextString.Length - 1, 1);
                        }
                        else if (key == Keys.Space)
                        {
                            TextString = TextString.Insert(TextString.Length, " ");
                        }
                        else if (key == Keys.Enter)
                        {
                            this.IsFinished = true;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            string keyString = key.ToString();
                            bool isUpperCase = ((Control.IsKeyLocked(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock) &&
                                                 (!currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift) &&
                                                  !currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))) ||
                                                (!Control.IsKeyLocked(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock) &&
                                                 (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift) ||
                                                  currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))));

                            if (keyString.Length == 1)
                            {
                                TextString += isUpperCase ? keyString.ToUpper() : keyString.ToLower();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

It's important to note that I needed a reference to windows.forms for the upper case stuff(I'm sure there's a better way, but i'm in a hurry here so :P )

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if C# 7 will allow pattern matching like this but other F# users might also look for something like this like I did.

```
override this.Update(gameTime) =
  let HandleKeys K =
         match K with
         | Keys.Down -> DoSomething
         | Keys.Up -> DoSomethingElse
         | Keys.Left -> DoYetSomethingElse
         | Keys.Right->  DoAnythingOtherThanWhatWeDidAlready

  if Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length > 0 then HandleKeys (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().[0]) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time writing this for one of my projects. Have a look over it I think one of the keys may be wrong but here it is.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace EEngine.IO
{
static class EKeyboard
{
    public static Keys GetKeyFromString(string keyStr)
    {
        MonoGame.Framework.Keys key;

        switch (keyStr.ToUpper())
        {
            // Letters
            case "Q":
                key = Keys.Q;
                return key;
            case "W":
                key = Keys.W;
                return key;
            case "E":
                key = Keys.E;
                return key;
            case "R":
                key = Keys.R;
                return key;
            case "T":
                key = Keys.T;
                return key;
            case "Y":
                key = Keys.Y;
                return key;
            case "U":
                key = Keys.U;
                return key;
            case "I":
                key = Keys.I;
                return key;
            case "O":
                key = Keys.O;
                return key;
            case "P":
                key = Keys.P;
                return key;
            case "A":
                key = Keys.A;
                return key;
            case "S":
                key = Keys.S;
                return key;
            case "D":
                key = Keys.D;
                return key;
            case "F":
                key = Keys.F;
                return key;
            case "G":
                key = Keys.G;
                return key;
            case "H":
                key = Keys.H;
                return key;
            case "J":
                key = Keys.J;
                return key;
            case "K":
                key = Keys.K;
                return key;
            case "L":
                key = Keys.L;
                return key;
            case "Z":
                key = Keys.Z;
                return key;
            case "X":
                key = Keys.X;
                return key;
            case "C":
                key = Keys.C;
                return key;
            case "V":
                key = Keys.V;
                return key;
            case "B":
                key = Keys.B;
                return key;
            case "N":
                key = Keys.N;
                return key;
            case "M":
                key = Keys.M;
                return key;

            // TOP ROW F# KEYS ETC.
            case "ESCAPE":
                key = Keys.Escape;
                return key;
            case "F1":
                key = Keys.F1;
                return key;
            case "F2":
                key = Keys.F2;
                return key;
            case "F3":
                key = Keys.F3;
                return key;
            case "F4":
                key = Keys.F4;
                return key;
            case "F5":
                key = Keys.F5;
                return key;
            case "F6":
                key = Keys.F6;
                return key;
            case "F7":
                key = Keys.F7;
                return key;
            case "F8":
                key = Keys.F8;
                return key;
            case "F9":
                key = Keys.F9;
                return key;
            case "F10":
                key = Keys.F10;
                return key;
            case "F11":
                key = Keys.F11;
                return key;
            case "F12":
                key = Keys.F12;
                return key;
            case "PRINTSCR":
                key = Keys.PrintScreen;
                return key;
            case "SCROLLLOCK":
                key = Keys.Scroll;
                return key;
            case "PAUSE":
                key = Keys.Pause;
                return key;

            // SECOND ROW NUMBERS, ETC
            case "`":
                key = Keys.OemTilde;
                return key;
            case "1":
                key = Keys.D1;
                return key;
            case "2":
                key = Keys.D2;
                return key;
            case "3":
                key = Keys.D3;
                return key;
            case "4":
                key = Keys.D4;
                return key;
            case "5":
                key = Keys.D5;
                return key;
            case "6":
                key = Keys.D6;
                return key;
            case "7":
                key = Keys.D7;
                return key;
            case "8":
                key = Keys.D8;
                return key;
            case "9":
                key = Keys.D9;
                return key;
            case "0":
                key = Keys.D0;
                return key;
            case "-":
                key = Keys.OemMinus;
                return key;
            case "+":
                key = Keys.OemPlus;
                return key;
            case "BACKSPACE":
                key = Keys.Back;
                return key;
            case "INSERT":
                key = Keys.Insert;
                return key;
            case "HOME":
                key = Keys.Home;
                return key;
            case "PGUP":
                key = Keys.PageUp;
                return key;
            case "NUMLOCK":
                key = Keys.NumLock;
                return key;
            case "/":
                key = Keys.OemPipe; // <- NEED TO VERIFY
                return key;
            case "*":
                key = Keys.Multiply;
                return key;
            case "TAB":
                key = Keys.Tab;
                return key;
            case "ENTER":
                key = Keys.Enter;
                return key;
            case "DELETE":
                key = Keys.Delete;
                return key;
            case "END":
                key = Keys.End;
                return key;
            case "PGDN":
                key = Keys.PageDown;
                return key;
            case "CAPS":
                key = Keys.CapsLock;
                return key;
            case "LSHIFT":
                key = Keys.LeftShift;
                return key;
            case "RSHIFT":
                key = Keys.RightShift;
                return key;
            case "LCTRL":
                key = Keys.LeftControl;
                return key;
            case "LALT":
                key = Keys.LeftAlt;
                return key;
            case "RALT":
                key = Keys.RightAlt;
                return key;
            case "RCTRL":
                key = Keys.RightControl;
                return key;
            case "SPACE":
                key = Keys.Space;
                return key;
            case "KP_INS":
                key = Keys.NumPad0;
                return key;
            case "KP_END":
                key = Keys.NumPad1;
                return key;
            case "KP_DOWNARROW":
                key = Keys.NumPad2;
                return key;
            case "KP_PGDN":
                key = Keys.NumPad3;
                return key;
            case "KP_LEFTARROW":
                key = Keys.NumPad4;
                return key;
            case "KP_5":
                key = Keys.NumPad5;
                return key;
            case "KP_RIGHTARROW":
                key = Keys.NumPad6;
                return key;
            case "KP_HOME":
                key = Keys.NumPad7;
                return key;
            case "KP_UPARROW":
                key = Keys.NumPad8;
                return key;
            case "KP_PGUP":
                key = Keys.NumPad9;
                return key;
            case "UP":
                key = Keys.Up;
                return key;
            case "DOWN":
                key = Keys.Down;
                return key;
            case "LEFT":
                key = Keys.Left;
                return key;
            case "RIGHT":
                key = Keys.Right;
                return key;
        }

        return Keys.OemQuestion; // <- RETURN QUESTION AS "NO SUCH KEY"
    }

    public static string GetStringFromKey(Keys key)
    {
        string keyStr = "?";

        switch (key)
        {
            // Letters
            case Keys.Q:
                keyStr = "Q";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.W:
                keyStr = "W";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.E:
                keyStr = "E";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.R:
                keyStr = "R";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.T:
                keyStr = "T";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Y:
                keyStr = "Y";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.U:
                keyStr = "U";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.I:
                keyStr = "I";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.O:
                keyStr = "O";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.P:
                keyStr = "P";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.A:
                keyStr = "A";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.S:
                keyStr = "S";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D:
                keyStr = "D";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F:
                keyStr = "F";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.G:
                keyStr = "G";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.H:
                keyStr = "H";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.J:
                keyStr = "J";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.K:
                keyStr = "K";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.L:
                keyStr = "L";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Z:
                keyStr = "Z";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.X:
                keyStr = "X";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.C:
                keyStr = "C";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.V:
                keyStr = "V";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.B:
                keyStr = "B";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.N:
                keyStr = "N";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.M:
                keyStr = "M";
                return keyStr;

            // TOP ROW F# keyStrS ETC.
            case Keys.Escape:
                keyStr = "ESCAPE";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F1:
                keyStr = "F1";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F2:
                keyStr = "F2";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F3:
                keyStr = "F3";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F4:
                keyStr = "F4";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F5:
                keyStr = "F5";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F6:
                keyStr = "F6";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F7:
                keyStr = "F7";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F8:
                keyStr = "F8";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F9:
                keyStr = "F9";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F10:
                keyStr = "F10";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F11:
                keyStr = "F11";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.F12:
                keyStr = "F12";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.PrintScreen:
                keyStr = "PRINTSCR";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Scroll:
                keyStr = "SCROLLLOCK";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Pause:
                keyStr = "PAUSE";
                return keyStr;

            // SECOND ROW NUMBERS, ETC
            case Keys.OemTilde:
                keyStr = "`";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D1:
                keyStr = "1";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D2:
                keyStr = "2";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D3:
                keyStr = "3";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D4:
                keyStr = "4";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D5:
                keyStr = "5";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D6:
                keyStr = "6";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D7:
                keyStr = "7";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D8:
                keyStr = "8";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D9:
                keyStr = "9";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.D0:
                keyStr = "0";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.OemMinus:
                keyStr = "-";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.OemPlus:
                keyStr = "+";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Back:
                keyStr = "BACKSPACE";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Insert:
                keyStr = "INSERT";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Home:
                keyStr = "HOME";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.PageUp:
                keyStr = "PGUP";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumLock:
                keyStr = "NUMLOCK";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.OemPipe: // <- NEED TO VERIFY
                keyStr = "/";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Multiply:
                keyStr = "*";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Tab:
                keyStr = "TAB";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Enter:
                keyStr = "ENTER";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Delete:
                keyStr = "DELETE";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.End:
                keyStr = "END";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.PageDown:
                keyStr = "PGDN";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.CapsLock:
                keyStr = "CAPS";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.LeftShift:
                keyStr = "LSHIFT";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.RightShift:
                keyStr = "RSHIFT";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.LeftControl:
                keyStr = "LCTRL";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.LeftAlt:
                keyStr = "LALT";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.RightAlt:
                keyStr = "RALT";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.RightControl:
                keyStr = "RCTRL";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Space:
                keyStr = "SPACE";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad0:
                keyStr = "KP_INS";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad1:
                keyStr = "KP_END";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad2:
                keyStr = "KP_DOWNARROW";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad3:
                keyStr = "KP_PGDN";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad4:
                keyStr = "KP_LEFTARROW";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad5:
                keyStr = "KP_5";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad6:
                keyStr = "KP_RIGHTARROW";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad7:
                keyStr = "KP_HOME";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad8:
                keyStr = "KP_UPARROW";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.NumPad9:
                keyStr = "KP_PGUP";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Up:
                keyStr = "UP";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Down:
                keyStr = "DOWN";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Left:
                keyStr = "LEFT";
                return keyStr;
            case Keys.Right:
                keyStr = "RIGHT";
                return keyStr;
        }

        return keyStr; // <- RETURN QUESTION AS "NO SUCH KEY"
    }
}
}
```

There are two methods - GetKeyFromString(string keyStr) and GetStringFromKey(Keys key) and you can call them from anywhere like

```
EKeyboard.GetKeyFromString("A");
```