# In Regards to Android On-Screen Keyboard Input

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, monogame, on-screen-keyboard

I have been following this example ([Open On-Screen Keyboard for Xamarin/Monogame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810168/open-on-screen-keyboard-for-xamarin-monogame)) for hooking up the SoftInput to my Xamarin MonoGame Android app.  The problem I'm having is catching the OnKeyPress events.  As the poster has it listed there, I simply need a private OnKeyPress void, without an override tag, but that seems wrong to me, and in practice it does not work.  I can get the OSK to appear and disappear at appropriate times, but I'm not seeming to catch the OnKeyPress events.  Is the way he describes it there not correct?  (I would simply comment on the question and ask this, but I can't post comments because of this silly reputation system which forces me to ask a bunch of questions before I can reply to questions.)

Code for the OnKeyPress event, as created by following his example:

```
private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //does stuff
}
```

Shouldn't that be a protected override?  But I can't seem to find a suitable method in Android.Activity to override.  Kinda lost here, please lend me some assistance :(

Comment: Assuming you are trying to capture key presses that are NOT captured by any other Views, override `Activity.OnKeyDown`. If you are trying to capture `TextView` key presses, implement a `ITextWatcher` and add it to your `TextView` via  `AddTextChangedListener`. As far as the linked SO, I do not see how `OnKeyPress` would ever do anything as it is not being triggered from anything in that SO answer and `AndroidGameActivity` is a subclass of 'Activity` and that game activity has no `OnKeyPress` method either...

Comment: The view's methods arent really used too much as it's a MonoGame app, so I'm mostly handling input from TouchCollection each frame, and I don't use any standard android controls. I have my own class for textbox that I've made which is what I'm trying to send the input TO. I'll try your suggestion with the alternate event, thanks.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you just need to override `Activity.OnKeyDown` (or maybe `OnKeyUp` depending upon your needs) : https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

Comment: I attempted to override OnKeyDown as you mentioned, but it's still not receiving the events when I touch keys on the OSK.  Here's how I set up the method:
`public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        { }`